# Subscriber does not work on new thread when subscribeOn is called on object reference

Tags: rx-android, rx-java2

Today I spent a lot of time debugging why new thread wasn't created even when I have mentioned so.

```
Observable<DoctorProfileMessage> observable = Observable.defer(
new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends DoctorProfileMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<? extends DoctorProfileMessage> call() throws Exception {
        return Observable.just(getDummyProfile());
    }
});
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
observable.subscribe(.....)
```

It created new thread when, I changed code to:

```
Observable<DoctorProfileMessage> observable = Observable.defer(
new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends DoctorProfileMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<? extends DoctorProfileMessage> call() throws Exception {
        return Observable.just(getDummyProfile());
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

I am trying to understand why it behaves differently in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

Operators return a new `Observable` which you should continue chainging but your first code applies and then drops the result of the `subscribeOn().observeOn()` and subscribes to the original, unmodified source.

```
Observable<DoctorProfileMessage> original = Observable.defer(
new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends DoctorProfileMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<? extends DoctorProfileMessage> call() throws Exception {
        return Observable.just(getDummyProfile());
    }
});
Observable<DoctorProfileMessage> withSchedulers =  
    original.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

original.subscribe(.....); // <------------- chains are immutable in their composition

withSchedulers.subscribe(...);
```